# how do I change the CSS for a GTK application?

Tags: gnome, gtk, css

I am looking a bit more in-depth at GTK styling - using GTK-Inspector to look at various settings.

Specifically I'm looking at CSS styling.

Under Ubuntu 16.04 GTK-Inspector correctly displays my revised CSS styling.

Under Ubuntu 16.10 it doesn't ... So anybody any ideas what the secret trick is to change the CSS for a GTK application using GTK-Inspector?

16.10:

CSS styling - the button labels do not change to red

[image]

16.04:

CSS styling - the button labels correctly change to red
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The CSS conventions have changed in GTK+3.20 compared to GTK+3.18

If you look at the GTK documentation - CSS Nodes section

[image]

for [GtkLabel](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html) the CSS should now be

```
label { color: red; };
```

in GTK+3.18 the CSS Node was GtkLabel i.e.

```
GtkLabel { color: red; }
```