# Can the "Starred" folder in the left pane of Files (nautilus) be removed?

Tags: nautilus

On Ubuntu 19.10, I disable tracker because I do not like how my computer is overheating for several minutes after startup, and because I prefer full text search not be enabled in the file manager by default. The "Star" feature [relies on Tracker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148262/where-is-the-starred-directory-in-the-nautilus-sidebar-stored) and therefore does not work when tracker is disabled.

No option to disable the "Starred" folder is exposed in the Nautilus preferences, nor is a dconf setting available. The file `user-dirs-dir` determines the "special user folders" displayed in the left pane, but not the "Recent" or "Starred" items.

The question is: can the "Starred" item in the left pane (bookmark pane) of Files (nautilus) be removed?

Comment: @starkus, vanadium, do either of you have experience with [GTK Inspector](https://askubuntu.com/q/856059/248158)? Perhaps, you could use "CSS" to hide what you don't want to see?

Comment: @JusticeforMonica I have no clue about GTK Inspector :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [a couple of not that trivial ways](https://superuser.com/questions/1359253/how-to-remove-starred-tab-in-gnomes-nautilus) to remove the "Starred" item in the left bar of nautilus. The second option involves editing source code and recompiling. I will only cover the first way here.

1 - Create a folder to store the override

```
mkdir ~/.config/nautilus/ui
```

2 - Extract the resource description of the main window:

```
gresource extract /bin/nautilus \
/org/gnome/nautilus/ui/nautilus-window.ui \
> ~/.config/nautilus/ui/nautilus-window.ui
```

3 - Edit the properties of the GtkPlacesSidebar object: open the file you created in the previous step:

```
gedit ~/.config/nautilus/ui/nautilus-window.ui
```

and change the property `show-starred-location` to `false` as in following code snippet:

```
<object class="GtkPlacesSidebar" id="places_sidebar">
...
<property name="show-recent">False</property>
<property name="show-starred-location">False</property>
...
</object>
```

4 - Set the environment variable to make GLib use this override:

```
export G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS="/org/gnome/nautilus/ui=$HOME/.config/nautilus/ui"
```

5 - You also need to set this via ~/.pam_environment, because Nautilus is started via D-Bus:

```
gedit ~/.pam_environment
```

and add following line

```
G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS DEFAULT="/org/gnome/nautilus/ui=/home/confetti/.config/nautilus/ui"
```

where you change "confetti" by your own login name.

(with thanks to JusticeforMonica and DK Bose for the hints)

You need to log out and back in before this will take effect.

Comment: `<property name="show-recent">False</property>` does not exist for me (ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: I added `<property name="show-recent">False</property>`, but, unfortunately, it did nothing. However, with your recipe I removed starred.

Comment: Had to log out and then back in for this to take effect.

Comment: @electrovir thank you, I added this, and in the mean time I corrected `gresource`:  I apparently missed the comment of @Ufos who hinted to this error, for which also thanks.

Comment: @Ufos, `show-recent` is another topic about the `Recent` folder, which is controlled by `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-recent-files false`, value `false` means hides it..