# How can one remove the "Favorites" bookmark in nautilus sidebar?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

How do I remove the ["Favorites"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8pA7.jpg) bookmark in GNOME Nautilus 40.2 from the sidebar?

I was not able to find a solution to this anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the "Starred" folder in the left pane of Files (nautilus) be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194319/can-the-starred-folder-in-the-left-pane-of-files-nautilus-be-removed)

Comment: Yes this was exactly my issue thanks for the redirect!